# Adding Ringtone to Notification Sound

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone

I would like to add a ringtone selected from a list of ringtones to my notification, using the `NotificationCompat.Builder` `setSound()` method. I am passing the correct URI as I put in a break point. The value is  **"content/mdia/internal/audio/media/64"** however this sound does not play when the notification is triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you spell the URI correctly? You have "content/mdia/...". Should that be "content/m**e**dia/..."?

Comment: Thanks, I fat fingered that in here but the actual code passed the URI in  a variable. I think my solution was more obvious and embarrassing than that. My notification volume was turned down. So even though when I selected my ringtone and it was loud, when the notification went off it was really low, the notification volume is a different control. I have a S5 so not sure if that is the case with other phones where the notification volume is different than the regular volume.